# PDFTron html2pdf 0KB file size

Tags: pdf-generation, node-modules, html2pdf, hapi, pdftron

I have the `@pdftron` node module installed in a test Node (Hapi) application on my Mac.  I'm trying to generate a PDF file from a HTML string but the saved file is 0 KB.  I've tried this two ways:

- By implementing the example code in the GET handler for a route
  configured in index.js
- By running the sample scripts that are
  installed  at
  `node_modules/@pdftron/pdfnet-node/samples/HTML2PDFTest/NODEJS/HTML2PDFTest.js`

In both cases, any new PDFs that are saved have a size of 0KB and any existing PDFs that are supposed to be modified by the process remain unchanged.

I've checked that the `html2pdf` module library path is being set correctly.

The route handler code is as follows, which is in accordance with example code provided by PDFTRon.

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/pdftron/html',
    handler: (request, h) => {

        const { PDFNet } = require('@pdftron/pdfnet-node/lib/pdfnet.js')

        const main = async () => {
            await PDFNet.initialize()
            await PDFNet.HTML2PDF.setModulePath('node_modules/@pdftron/pdfnet-node/lib')
            const output_path = '/tmp/'

            try {

                const html2pdf = await PDFNet.HTML2PDF.create();
                const doc = await PDFNet.PDFDoc.create();
                const html = '<html><body><h1>Heading</h1><p>Paragraph.</p></body></html>'
        
                html2pdf.insertFromHtmlString(html);
                await html2pdf.convert(doc);
                doc.save(output_path.concat('pdf2html.pdf'), PDFNet.SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_linearized);

            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }

        }
    
        PDFNet.runWithCleanup(main, 0).then(function () { PDFNet.shutdown(); })
        return 'PDF2HTML Test'
    }
})
```

Any thoughts/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I recently used `puppeteer` package for html2pdf conversion and it worked perfectly for me

Comment: Thanks, we've tried that but want to avoid having to use headkess Chrome and using screenshots.  We need more control and also PDF/A compliance

Comment: pdftron is not free i guess

Comment: That's not a problem

Comment: ask for support from the company

Comment: Yup, I already had and was waiting for feedback - see update below.

Answer (score 1):

Update on this - I had feedback from PDFTron to say that there is currently an issue with the current stable release of the Mac OS build and that they are addressing it.

In the meantime, they pointed me to the nightly experimental builds [here](https://www.pdftron.com/nightly/#experimental/).  I downloaded and installed a recent experimental build and the PDF files now save OK using that.